# FastAPI query parameter conversion to MongoDB aggregation

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

I have built a Flask web app that lists Songs I play on Guitar.

Now I am in the process of migrating all of my MongoDB aggregations from Flask, into a FastAPI service. One of the features allows me to filter songs (based on category and/or proficiency), thus generating a querystring, which was interpreted as a dictionary and passed into the $match stage of the aggregation, with an all-important 'songs.' parent preceding the keys.

**Question**
I have replicated the feature in FastAPI using a series of conditions (below). It works ok, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of creating the '$match'? i.e by:

- Counting the number of params and then injecting them as a dictionary into the aggregation
- Looping within the aggregation

I have read the FastAPI documentation about params, but it only really covers defining and validating them.

**Fast API route**

```py
@api.get("/songsets/{username}/songs", response_description="List all songs for users")
async def list_songs(username, category: str | None = None,  proficiency: int | None = None):

    if category or proficiency:
        if category and not proficiency:
            songs_pipeline =[
                { "$match" : { "user_name" : username } },
                { "$unwind" : "$songs"},
                    { "$match" :
                                {"songs.category" : category }
                        },
                { "$project" : { "_id" : 0,
                    "song" : "$songs.song",
                    "artist" : "$songs.artist",
                    }
                    }
                ]
        elif proficiency and not category:
            songs_pipeline =[
                { "$match" : { "user_name" : username } },
                { "$unwind" : "$songs"},
                    { "$match" :[
                            {"songs.category" : category },
                            {"songs.proficiency" : proficiency }
                            ]
                        },
                { "$project" : { "_id" : 0,
                    "song" : "$songs.song",
                    "artist" : "$songs.artist"
                    }
                    }
                ]
        elif proficiency and category:
            songs_pipeline =[
                { "$match" : { "user_name" : username } },
                { "$unwind" : "$songs"},
                    { "$match" :
                                {"songs.proficiency" : proficiency }
                        },
                { "$project" : { "_id" : 0,
                    "song" : "$songs.song",
                    "artist" : "$songs.artist",
                    }
                    }
                ]
        
        songs = await db["userSongSet_dev"].aggregate(songs_pipeline).to_list(100)
        return songs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the query looks good.

and there is some repetition key of the query,
how about this?

```
@api.get("/songsets/{username}/songs", response_description="List all songs for users")
async def list_songs(username, category: str | None = None,  proficiency: int | None = None):

    songs_pipeline = [
        { "$match" : { "user_name" : username } }, 
        { "$unwind" : "$songs"},
        { "$project" : { 
            "_id" : 0,
            "song" : "$songs.song",
            "artist" : "$songs.artist",
            }
        }
    ]
    math_position: int = 2
    
    if category or proficiency:
        if category and not proficiency:
            //ensure the position below after $unwind
            songs_pipeline.insert(math_position, { "$match" : {"songs.category" : 'category' } })
        elif proficiency and not category:
            songs_pipeline.insert(math_position, { "$match" :[
                            {"songs.category" : category },
                            {"songs.proficiency" : proficiency }
                            ]
                        })
            
        elif proficiency and category:
            songs_pipeline.insert(math_position, { "$match" : {"songs.proficiency" : proficiency } })
            
        songs = await db["userSongSet_dev"].aggregate(songs_pipeline).to_list(100)
        return songs
```

Comment: idk yet how to use python, let me know if i did wrong in any syntax.

Comment: Thanks! What does 'math_position: int = 2' do? Inject into the aggregation?

Comment: best practice requirements, `if a variable used more than once, better to put it as constanta`. and it used to define index position inside the `list`  which is have to be in below of `$unwind`.

Comment: Oh I see... Of course! I'd never looked at an aggregation pipeline as a list!

Comment: my bad, i didn't know about that. im still learning Python.

Comment: Same. I'll give it a go on Sunday and tick you if it works.